# ASP server side integer

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a webserver hosting an ASP program created in VB.NET.

Here is what I want to do:

I want a global Integer hosted on the server.

Anyone who visits the webpage will be able to increase the single integer on the server by pressing a button (`btnAdd`)

When the button is pressed, the app will go back to the server and increase the global integer, then display the total number on the webpage.

So if 2 people are on it, they both press it once when it's at 0, they'll both see 2.

Networking is my weak suite. Can someone tell me the best approach for this?
JSON? XML? SQL?

Here's all the code I have for now.

```
Protected Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim intCount As Integer = -1
    intCount = CInt(lblCount.Text.ToString)
    intCount = intCount + 1
    lblCount.Text = intCount
End Sub
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Sorry for the new account, I can't find my old one. Thanks!

Comment: You would have to store the value, in a database of some sort. It can be a simple xml file, or an actual database. If you don't store it anywhere, upon every restart of the application host service, you will lose the data. You'd also want to read the integer from database and increase it there, instead of reading it from the lblCount. And you would need to bind lblCount to the data, so upon load/reload it get's the new number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an application variable eg:

```
Application("lblCount") = Application("lblCount") +1
```

The variable will remain current as long as the server will run. There is no persistence if the server (or the IIS service) is restarted. Depending on what you are trying to achieve you will probably have to store the value in a database or in a file.